# How do you PerformClick(); for a button on a different tab?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, button, event-handling

I'm using Visual c# express 2010, I have 3 tabs and on the first tab there is a button that exits the program. I'm trying to call that button click on the 2nd and 3rd tab with

```
btnExit.PerformClick();
```

but since it isn't visible nothing happens. How would I call the invisible button click?

any help would be appreciated

EDIT:
Thanks for the replies, the two answers work great but I found a way that I think is easier and better.

instead of systematically changing tabs or calling a whole different method, I did this

```
btnExit_Click(sender, e);
```

I can put that in any other button click and it works great, very simple to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myTabs.SelectedTab = specificTab;
btnExit.PerformClick();
```

Comment: Edited the snippet. First activate the tab then perform click. After this, you can get back to the initial tab.

Comment: whichever the tab that button lives on.

Answer (score 6):

I think it's better to create a method that actually has the code to exit the program, and call that method from btnExit click event and also other buttons click event, than PerformClick of the exit button.

```
void ExitApplication()
{
   // code to exit the application
}

protected void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ExitApplication();
}
protected void ButtonInOtherTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ExitApplication();
}
```

This way it's easier to read and understand.

Comment: yes this is a little easier if I just wanted it to exit the application. But there is other code that runs when I press the initial exit button, like saving entered text and such. It would be much easier to call the button then to right code for each button.

Comment: but I guess I could put that code in the ExitApplication() method as well. Thanks, I may do that.